# Reduce load time on jQuery color animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make each span rotate between a random color on 3sec intervals.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WERFJ/21/

```
<h1><span class="first">TEXT1</span> <span class="second">TEXT2</span> <span class="third">TEXT3</span></h1>
```

Currently I'm using the below code and the [jquery.animate-colors](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/) plugin. Is there any way to make this run or get the same effect faster. Chrome can handle it but FF often crashes. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
        spectrum();  

            function spectrum(){  
                var hue1 = 'rgb(' + 128 + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
                var hue2 = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + 128 + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';  
                var hue3 = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + 128 + ')';  

                $('.first').animate( { color: hue1 }, 3000);
                $('.second').animate( { color: hue2 }, 3000);
                $('.third').animate( { color: hue3 }, 3000); 
                spectrum();  
        }  
    });
```

Comment: I think your problem is that the recursive call is not waiting for the animations to finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that the recursive call is not waiting for the animations to finish. by adding the call as a callback to the last animate call you will be only recalling it when the last ones are done instead of queueing and infinite chain of animations. http://jsfiddle.net/WERFJ/23/ it seems to work fine in firefox now

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    spectrum();

    function spectrum() {
        var hue1 = 'rgb(' + 128 + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
        var hue2 = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + 128 + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
        var hue3 = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + 128 + ')';

        $('.first').animate({
            color: hue1
        }, 3000);
        $('.second').animate({
            color: hue2
        }, 3000);
        $('.third').animate({
            color: hue3
        }, 3000, spectrum);
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

The initial delay from the user's point of view is because the browser won't update the display until your function finishes running, but your function just keeps calling itself recursively until there's a stack overflow - or, in FF I got a "too much recursion" error. It's only after the "too much recursion" error crashes the function that all the queued animations actually start working.

You can avoid this by changing the last line of your function to use `setTimeout()` to queue up another call rather than having it call itself directly:

```
setTimeout(spectrum,3100);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WERFJ/24/

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.when` to wrap the animations, and `then()` to run the next series. jQuery deferred object then assures that all animations are complete before starting over again

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/WERFJ/26/

```
var anim_1 = $('.first').animate({ color: hue1}, 3000);
var anim_2 = $('.second').animate({color: hue2}, 3000);
var anim_3 = $('.third').animate({color: hue3}, 3000);

$.when(anim_1, anim_2, anim_3).then(spectrum);
```